# Eigen assert in a function called from variadic template function

Tags: c++, eigen, variadic-functions

I have a small lib based on Eigen 3.3.9 with all the interesting parts here in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sYrz5qqsv). The problem is it crashes (Godbolt reports return code 139 instead of 0), and I don't know why. The crash happens here in Eigen, because `rows()` and `cols()` calls refer to null pointer in nested objects. Here, `row = 0, col = 0, this = @0x7fffffffdf60  Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1> ...` although not a single member appears.

```cpp
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Scalar&
    operator()(Index row, Index col)
    {
      eigen_assert(row >= 0 && row < rows()
          && col >= 0 && col < cols());
      return coeffRef(row, col);
    }
```

which gets called directly from here:

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd PolynomApprox::doCalculateVandermonde(uint32_t const aVariableIndex, uint32_t const aSampleCount, double const * const aSamplesX, uint32_t const aDegree) {
  Eigen::MatrixXd result(aSampleCount, aDegree + 1u);

  for(uint32_t i = 0u; i < aSampleCount; ++i) {
    for(uint32_t j = 0u; j <= aDegree; ++j) {
       result(i, j) = ::pow(normalize(aSamplesX[i], aVariableIndex), j);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This used to work in the previous version without variadic template function.
Why does this happen?
Thanks in advance: Balázs Bámer

Comment: Problem is with `std::fill_n(mActualExponents.begin(), mVariableCount, 0u);` because range is empty (size of `mActualExponents` returns 0), and you try to fill 1 items of its.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, this is really wrong. I will try it.

Comment: Unfortunately no change. In fact, the wrong `fill_n` call would be after the failure.

Comment: Can you try to further reduce your failing code to a [mre]? (Remove all parts which are not necessary to reproduce the crash)

Comment: Perhaps, when I have time. I needed a solution, so I threw away variadic templates and uset std::initializer_list instead.